# Can I use the refresh token with omniauth-37signals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, omniauth, basecamp

The basecamp API gives me a refresh token which I stores, but I can't seem to see that the omniauth-37signals gem supports refreshing the token. Do anyone have some tips on how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `oauth2` gem, I believe you can use the `refresh!` method here:

https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/blob/master/lib/oauth2/access_token.rb#L76-L90

If not, perhaps you can reverse-engineer that `refresh!` method to build your own refresh mechanism.